# get email alert for threat detection on azure vm by security center

Tags: azure, security, iaas

can anyone help me to get email alert for azure vm when an attack is detected by azure security center. i'm trying to run few queries in log analytics but i don't know what queries i will use for different types of attacks like brute-force attack and sql-injection attack etc.
used query:
SecurityDetection | where AlertTitle == "Failed SSH brute force attack"

Comment: If the answer works, please help mark it as an answer. It would help others. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive an alert for whatever types of attack, you can put all the AlertTitle in a list. Query like below:

```
  SecurityDetection 
  | where AlertTitle in ("Failed SSH brute force attack","another type of attack 1","another type of attack 2")
```